# Google Maps API - Get Property Boundary Data

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am looking for a way to extract built in property boundary data from the Google API to know where to highlight areas for information needs.

It's easy enough drawing a polygon, but I want to know where to draw it in a more automated fashion. Perhaps similar to Geocoding for extracting an address location, except the geocoder only provides a central coordinate and a bounding box (for screen navigation) unfortunately.

Does Google provide this property data in some form?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having looked through the Maps APIs fairly extensively and no one suggesting otherwise. I think it's pretty conclusive Google Maps does not provide property boundaries.

The best way to go is to look for a service that does have the data to integrate into Maps, but likely costs money.

As an example these may be:

- Your local government's land services
- RPData.com - http://www.rpdata.com/residential_property_information/residential_property_information.html
- ReportAllUSA.com (if you are American) - http://reportallusa.com/

None of these are guaranteed, looking into them myself, but may also be different from person to person depending on costs. If I find a free one, I'll give a shout.

Comment: I was looking for this very thing. The links you provided were definitely helpful. Please report back if you find anything new.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to implement this on **Australian Region**.
State & Local councils have open data free for usage.

I am working with Brisbane, QLD Australia:

For Brisbane: https://www.data.brisbane.qld.gov.au/data/dataset?q=parcel
For QLD: https://www.data.qld.gov.au/dataset?q=parcel

P.S **parcel dataset** contains information about individual Property Listings. It does have a learning curve & takes sometime to use open data.